# ArcMap Dynamic Text: Is it possible another layout text element in the same layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dynamic-text

Is it possible to use ArcMap dynamic text in one layout text element that references another layout text element? Essentially I want to just type something in one text element, and then that text to be automatically copied into the other text element.

So far I have come up with this tag:

```
<dyn "type="document" name="VERSION"/>
```

where "VERSION" is the name of the text element I want to reference. I have also tried:

```
<dyn type="layout" name="VERSION"/>
```

Both outputs are "[empty]".

The closest ESRI help page on the topic I could find was this one:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/add-and-modify-dynamic-text.htm

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is no you cannot reference text from another text element.  You can achieve this affect with a fudge if you don't use a particular mxd property.

Go to File > Map Document Properties and place some text you want to see in your text elements. I've placed it in Description.

[image: Map Document Properties]

Insert 2 text elements onto your layout and for the text properties place the code `<dyn type="document" property="description"/>` with what ever other text you desire.

[image: LAYOUT AND TEXT ELEMENTS]